# sql adding two columns of decimal data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, decimalformat

I have two columns EY_AmountIncl_LC,EY_AmountExcl_LC which are of data type `decimal(30,2)`. I want to add two columns as a result but while doing I am ending up with following result

```
EY_AmountIncl_LC    EY_AmountExcl_LC    result
7000.00000          7000.00000          7000.000007000.00000
```

two columns are concatenating but not giving the sum of two columns.desired output is

```
EY_AmountIncl_LC    EY_AmountExcl_LC    result
7000.00000          7000.00000          14000.00
```

I want to group by according to vendor number which is another column

```
vendornumber       result
10000064            0.10
10000064            0.10
10000064            2000.00
```

I need to get only one record with one vendor number example

```
vendornumber       result
10000064           sum(0.10+0.10+2000.00)
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you are using as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. ([edit] your question by clicking on the [edit] link. Do **not** post code in comments)

Comment: sql server management studio 2014

Comment: Please show us the query you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

USE [CONVERT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) function

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),EY_AmountIncl_LC)+
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),EY_AmountExcl_LC) AS result
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value after you add them:

```
select cast(EY_AmountIncl_LC + EY_AmountExcl_LC as decimal(30, 2)) as result;
```

The rules for the scale and precision of the result of an arithmetic expression on decimals are . . . complicate.  If you know what type you want then just cast the result to the appropriate type.

Comment: It might give error: `DECLARE @EY_AmountIncl_LC VARCHAR(100) ='7000.00000'
DECLARE @EY_AmountExcl_LC    VARCHAR(100) = '7000.00000'  

SELECT CAST(@EY_AmountIncl_LC+@EY_AmountExcl_LC AS DECIMAL(30, 2)) AS result;`